# Recommended installation for Asus EEE 1015PEM Netbook

Tags: unity, ubuntu-netbook

I just got my Asus EEE PC 1015PEM netbook with Windows 7 starter... obviously, I'd like to install Ubuntu (not sure yet if I'd like to dual boot or completely remove win7).

Anyway, I never had a netbook before. I know about unity but heard some bad stuff about it, so I wonder if I might be better sticking to the desktop edition. What do you think? any recommendations?

Also, should I use the 32 bit or 64 bit version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install the 32 bit* version of the Ubuntu 10.10 [netbook edition](http://www.ubuntu.com/netbook/get-ubuntu/download). It's fantastic. :-)

If anything doesn't work properly, you can always change your mind later. Or come here and ask a question about it.

If you install Ubuntu, you get the Desktop edition as well - and you can choose to start it instead of Unity when you log in, should it turn out not to work brilliantly for some reason.

There will be a lot of changes in Unity in April 2011, and you will get all of them once you upgrade, but for now, try it out and see if you like it. A lot of people do.

*: There's really no good reason to use 64 bit on this machine. 32 bits will work great.

Comment: did you mean the 32bit version of **unity**?

Comment: Sorry, yes I meant the netbook edition. Edited the answer.

Comment: Note: Unity is just one part of the netbook edition, namely the Shell (the part that provides a graphical environment). And it's going to be the default shell in the next version of Ubuntu. But you can always add and remove shells, and switch between them while the system is running. You are not committing yourself to the netbook edition by installing it. Other Shells are the Gnome desktop (ubuntu-desktop), the KDE Software compilation (kubuntu-desktop), XFCE (xubuntu-desktop) and a few more.

Comment: If you have any problems with the 3D requirements in Unity, try the 2D version which is in a PPA for 10.10 and will be available in 11.04.